# HTML5 get files in directory

Tags: html, filesystems

I want to simply find all images in the /images folder from my website and put them as strings in an Array. I heard you could do this with HTML5 filesystem API.

I already found this website http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

But it says how to make new folders or files...
Can't figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that same website it talks about creating a DirectoryReader to get the contents of a file, which is what it sounds like you want to do.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-dir-reading